# How to Authenticate Gmail like Google Talk to open new emails in browser

Tags: .net, authentication, browser, gmail

I can read new emails using gmail pop3 in c#, I'm looking for a way to open each one of new emails in browser just like **Google Talk**

When you receive new email Google talk notify you and if you click on message, you can read your email in browser new window. Any Idea?

Comment: I believe the command "firefox URL" will bring up a new firefox window/tab if you have firefox already running (or start a new firefox if you don't). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to authenticate gmail programmatically  using c#

Answer (score 1):

I've also tryed that, it seams it uses a clientlogin token, but it still didn't work for me, maybe its a special token that only people from inside google knows

The token is passed to the browser as a URL, like this:
https://www.google.com/accounts/TokenAuth?auth=[TOKEN]&service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail&source=googletalk

where the [TOKEN] string is a really big "random" string. if you are quick you can get the full URL, but it only works once, the token expires after the first login.
I have tried using google data API to use the clientlogi token, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved via Google Uber auth token, involved SID, LSID tokens obtained via Android AccountManager. 
Android browser auto-logins the same way, see the browser code: http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Browser/src/com/android/browser/GoogleAccountLogin.java